# Different view by logged user (Spring, java, thymeleaf)

Tags: java, spring, thymeleaf

I'm making a web application with spring and thymeleaf. My PM wants me to do a customizable view by each user (there will be a default - but every user can have a his own view). For example - after successful login there is a view with 4 buttons. To the app can log in 2 users, User1 and User2. User1 can only see 2 buttons, User 2 can see all of them. How can i do that?

I was thinking about 2 options:

1. `ViewResolvers`. For example  `InternalResourceViewResolver` - but, can it be scoped by session? If i would have all the html files in directories User1/... 
   User2/... 
   would `InternalResourceViewResolver` (after successful login) choose what views it should use ?
2. Use user roles (spring security). After login, set in session all the settings and then on the view check if user can see it or no (`th:if`).

Please for any help, source of information or what should i read to find right solution.

Comment: I don't know how to do with thymeleaf but with SpringSecurity and JSP you have the spring security taglib a tag that show it's content based on the user role.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you already use spring, use also Spring Security to manage authorization and authentication in your app. Then SpringSecurity has also a taglib for Thymeleaf that offer a tag to show content based on user authorizations, check this [link](http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/articles/springsecurity.html) for how to do it

Comment: I use Spring security and that's what i'm doing already - but i would like to make a application that admin set in configuration for a user1 - you can see button1 and button3. User2 can see button1, button2 and button3. And when they will log into application - that's already working. I'm not sure if doing as much roles as buttons/views/tables is a smart idea.

Comment: It depends if management wants to set the permission at buttons/views/tables granularity. :)

Comment: Yea that's true. In my case - management wants to set permission on that low level. Spring security authorization will be probably the easiest way to do this. Thanks a lot for help!